# Why does Schwartz discard the product of counterterms $\delta_2\delta_m$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, perturbation-theory, textbook-erratum

In Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model by Schwartz the author starts with the QED bare Lagrangian, defines $A_\mu^0 = \sqrt{Z_3}A_\mu$, $\psi^0 = \sqrt{Z_2}\psi$, $m_0=Z_m m_R$ and $e_0 = Z_e e_R$. Further defining $Z_1 = Z_eZ_2\sqrt{Z_3}$ the bare Lagrangian gets written as \begin{eqnarray}
{\cal L} &=& -\frac{1}{4}Z_3 F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+iZ_2\bar \psi\gamma^\mu{\partial_\mu}\psi- Z_2Z_m m_R\bar \psi\psi - e_R Z_1 \bar \psi \gamma^\mu A_\mu \psi.\tag{19.8}
\end{eqnarray}
Now he writes $$Z_i = 1+\delta_i.\tag{19.9+10}$$ The problem is that in the term $Z_2Z_m$ we would also have one term $\delta_2\delta_m$ in eq. (19.12) and this term is discarded by Schwartz.

I don't see how to justify it. I mean, even if you write a series expansion for each $\delta_i$ in powers of $e_R^2$ why would we just keep the leading result?

Being more explicit. Each $\delta_i$ starts at order $e_R^2$. Now say we want a result of order $e_R^4$. Clearly $\delta_2\delta_m$ should contribute because combining the two leading $O(e_R^2)$ contributions will give one $O(e_R^4)$ contribution.

So why one may just drop the $\delta_2\delta_m$ contribution as Schwartz seems to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, OP is correct: The counterterm in Schwartz eq. (19.12) should be $$Z_2Z_m-1~=~ (1+\delta_2)(1+\delta_m)-1~=~\delta_2+\delta_m+\color{red}{\delta_2\delta_m}.$$
See e.g. Peskin & Schroeder eq. (10.38).